# Back stack handling in Conductor

Tags: android, conductor

I try to use Conductor library but have a problem with backstack.
I have an activity with 4 buttons in bottom navigation panel.
Each of the buttons in ACTIVITY opens 1 of the 4 controllers:
- today news (root controller)
- trending news
- market news
- regulatory news

I need to add all controlers to backstack, and when i tap on the back button i must return to previous controller.
For example: 
Today -> Market -> Trending
If i tap on the back button in Trending controller, i must to return to Market e.t.c.
But now activity is closing when i tap on the back in any controller.
How can i implement this behavior?
This is the code in my activity:

```
    @Override
public void navigateToMarketHighlights() {
    MarketHighlightsController marketHighlightsController = new MarketHighlightsController();

    router.pushController(RouterTransaction.with(marketHighlightsController)
            .popChangeHandler(new FadeChangeHandler())
            .pushChangeHandler(new FadeChangeHandler()));
}

@Override
public void navigateToTrendingNow() {
    TrendingNowController trendingNowController = new TrendingNowController();

    router.pushController(RouterTransaction.with(trendingNowController)
            .popChangeHandler(new FadeChangeHandler())
            .pushChangeHandler(new FadeChangeHandler()));
}

@Override
public void navigateToTodayView() {
    TodayController todayController = new TodayController();

    router.pushController(RouterTransaction.with(todayController)
            .popChangeHandler(new FadeChangeHandler())
            .pushChangeHandler(new FadeChangeHandler()));
}

@Override
public void navigateToRegulatoryUpdatesView() {
    RegulatoryUpdatesController regulatoryUpdatesController = new RegulatoryUpdatesController();
    router.pushController(RouterTransaction.with(regulatoryUpdatesController)
            .popChangeHandler(new FadeChangeHandler())
            .pushChangeHandler(new FadeChangeHandler()));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you just forget to handle `onBackPressed()` in your `Activity`

`router.handleBack()` dealing with backstack navigation, so router pops backstack if this method called and returns `true`, othervise (e.g backstack is empty) it returns `false`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (!router.handleBack()) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had it in my code but it didn't work. 
I just restarted a studio and it works! )